# Syntax Error While Trying to Do Ternary Operation inside Return

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, conditional-operator

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong in this code? VS Code itself is saying that there's an error in the syntax in the code. It definitely is related to the brackets and javascript syntax but not sure what it is.

Here's the code:

```
   return (
            <>
                {
                    this.props.nested_row_number === 0 ?
                        <div className={`${this.props.header_col_class}`}>
                            
                        </div>
                        :
                        <div className={`${this.props.header_col_class}`}>
                                <div class="row">
                                    {
                        this.props.nested_row_number === 1 || this.props.nested_row_number === 2 || this.props.nested_row_number === 3 ?
                            
                                    <div className={`${this.props.nested_row_col_class}`}>
                                        
                                    </div>
    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            : <></>
                }
            </>
        )
```

Comment: Let me know if anyone has any questions.

Comment: In a situation like that why don't you try `switch`? Your code is a little unreadable for me

Comment: Not sure about switch because I'm trying to dynamically order elements automatically according to row and columns. User just has to enter column classname and whether it's nested row and the data will get rendered on frontend automatically. For example, if in backend you add 3 charts and you also add that there's 1 row with 3 columns attribute as col-4 then on frontend, it will automatically get rendered based on condition. For your case, you can just paste my code in VS Code editor and just see what's the issue.

Comment: @Robyn I've changed my code. Can you please now check what's the issue? I've made it very small

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, this should work.

````
(
    <>
        {
            this.props.nested_row_number === 0
                ?
                    <div className={`${this.props.header_col_class}`}>
                    </div>
                : 
                    <div className={`${this.props.header_col_class}`}>
                        <div class="row">
                            {
                                this.props.nested_row_number === 1 || this.props.nested_row_number === 2 || this.props.nested_row_number === 3 
                                    ?
                                        <div className={`${this.props.nested_row_col_class}`}></div>
                                    : <></>
                            }
                        </div>
                    </div>
        }
    </>
)```
````

Comment: Sometimes it helps to strip code completely and rebuild bit by bit until you figure out what's wrong when the current thing gets too big. You had a few extra `</divs>` and an extra ternary closure (`: </div>`) even though there weren't any open ones, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks! Now I'll try to remove the error for the original code that I had.